# Rails vs Ruby Version Clashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run a Rails app made by a third party. System dependencies as given on the repo are below:

> System dependencies
>
> Ruby version- ruby 2.4.2p198
>
> Rbenv version- rbenv 1.1.1
>
> Rails version 5.2.3
>
> Postgresql version- 1.1.4

I was able to install ruby 2.4, but when I try to install rails one of the gems fail to install because my ruby version is too old for it. Below is the screenshot of errors, I tried both installing rails and the specific gem separately.

[Error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBMf0.png)

I'm a total beginner on Ruby, and am currently extremely stuck. Anyone know how to surpass the error?

edit:added gemfile below. it looks like the failing gem racc isn't even used.. but rails doesnt install without it. should i just update ruby to 2.5 and take a chance?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.4.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'select2-rails', github: 'commutatus/select2-rails'
gem 'draper'
gem 'postmark'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'fast_jsonapi'
gem 'scout_apm'
# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootsnap'
gem 'popper_js', '~> 1.14.5'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "chartkick"

gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'kaminari',  github: 'amatsuda/kaminari'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 1.7.0'
gem 'bootstrap-glyphicons'
gem 'rails-assets-jgrowl', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'rails-assets-sweetalert2', '7.29.1', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'remotipart'
gem 'local_time'
gem 'rollbar'
gem 'paper_trail'
gem 'paper_trail-association_tracking'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.0.1'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'rails-assets-fullcalendar', source: 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'whenever', require: false
gem 'tzinfo'
gem 'zip-zip'
gem 'wicked_pdf', '1.4.0'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge'
gem 'nationality', '~> 1.0.3'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'money-rails', '~>1.12'
gem 'city-state'

#Cross-origin Resource Sharing
gem 'rack-cors'

# For Excel rendering
gem 'rubyzip', '>= 1.2.1'
gem 'caxlsx'
gem 'axlsx_rails'
gem "roo", "~> 2.8.0"

# Draggable functionality
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'acts_as_list'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development, :test, :staging do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
  gem 'fabrication'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'overcommit', '~> 0.47.0'
  gem 'coffeelint', '~> 1.16', '>= 1.16.1'
  gem 'rails_best_practices', '~> 1.19', '>= 1.19.4'
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.67.2'
  gem 'scss_lint', '~> 0.38.0', require: false
  gem "rubycritic", require: false

end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

#Cross-origin Resource Sharing
gem 'rack-cors'

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'acts_as_paranoid'
gem 'mimemagic', github: 'mimemagicrb/mimemagic', ref: '01f92d86d15d85cfd0f20dabd025dcbd36a8a60f'
```

Comment: Try installing a higher version of ruby. You can just install it with rbenv and then switch the local  version of the repository.

Comment: The problem may be that some of the dependencies are not pinned to the actual verion of the time the project was build and newer packages now require ruby 2.5.

Comment: Installing a higher ruby version might crash other things.

Comment: Please update with the Gemfile.

Comment: It does not hurt to install a higer version of ruby with rbenv and try. I would install 2.5 and change the .version file of the project and run bundler.

Comment: Please add your gemfile in the question as @ravans mentioned.

Comment: What version of racc is pinned in the gem file? Or does it have a verion pinned at all?

Comment: hi all, just added the gemfile

Answer (score 1):

The developers of the `racc` gem [removed support of Ruby 2.4](https://github.com/ruby/racc/commit/5af1a42a3bd2b5e0401e6198a7b3a7af245ef18b#diff-87a72357d0de4f573a9c8fac3db4324866bc328baffbf701c2355b7210ed89eb) not so long time ago.

One of the solutions might be to install `racc` from a specific commit which was made right before the breaking update.
Try to add this line to your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`

```rb
gem 'racc', git: 'https://github.com/ruby/racc.git', ref: 'd66cd1216669ec8acd05b57a4f0de76cc471938c'
```

Another solution is to use the previous version of the gem:

```rb
gem 'racc','~> 1.5.2'
```

Comment: but how do i get rails to install with this gem failing? is there a way to exclude this specific gem from the rails installation?

Comment: @DenizSS You should be able to install an earlier version of racc without the higher Ruby requirement even with Ruby 2.4 as your base. Try it with 1.4.16. That one seems old enough to not require 2.5.

Comment: @DenizSS racc is not directly referenced in your gem so it is a sub dependency. If you put it into your gem file like yakov mentioned above, you are gettin the right racc package and the sub dependency then should be resolved.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try to use this line, it will work with you.
First update the package index:

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Then use this line:

```
$ sudo apt install ruby-full
```

Comment: ruby is installed via .rbenv, further your are assuming the OP is using some debian derivative which the question does not state at all ...